# How to check Type before casting in java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, typechecking

I am casting my String variables to integer and double. I want to check whether the String variable contains valid Integer or Double value at runtime.

I us following code but it not works for me.

```
String var1="5.5";
String var2="6";
Object o1=var1;
Object o2=var2;
if (o1 instanceof Integer)
{
    qt += Integer.parseInt( var1);// Qty
}
if (o2 instanceof Double)
{
    wt += Double.parseDouble(var2);// Wt
}
```

Comment: o1 and o2 are definitely not instance of Integer as they both reference a String object

Comment: You are upcasting String into Object and hence o1 instanceOf Integer will never be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to parse the int and catch the exception if it fails:

```
String var1="5.5";

try {
 qt += Integer.parseInt( var1);
}    
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
// wasn't an int
}
```

Comment: I know this technique but i want to avoid excpetion to occur

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir.. This is what we call avoiding Exception to occur. We should handle them. And whether exception is raised or not, completely depends upon what string you are trying to convert. Of course you cannot convert `""`.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619603/no-tryparsedouble-in-java, or the question that one is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your `if` condition will certainly fail, because the `object` reference actually points to a String object. So, they are not instances of any `integer` or `double`.

To check whether a string can be converted to `integer` or `double`, you can either follow the approach in @Bedwyr's answer, or if you don't want to use `try-catch`, as I assume from your comments there (Actually, I don't understand why you don't want to use them), you can use a little bit of `pattern matching`: -

```
String str = "6.6";
String str2 = "6";

// If only digits are there, then it is integer
if (str2.matches("[+-]?\\d+")) {  
    int val = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    qt += val;
}

// digits followed by a `.` followed by digits
if (str.matches("[+-]?\\d+\\.\\d+")) {  
    double val = Double.parseDouble(str);
    wt += val;
}
```

But, understand that, `Integer.parseInt` and `Double.parseDouble` is the right way to do this. This is just an alternate approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use patterns to detect if a string is an integer or not :

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(var1);
  if (matcher.find()){
      // Your string is a number  
  } else {
      // Your string is not a number
  }
```

You will have to find the correct pattern (I haven't used them for awhile) or someone could edit my answer with the correct pattern.

****EDIT***** : Found a pattern for you. edited the code. I did not test it but it is taken from java2s site which also offer an even more elgant approach (copied from the site) :

```
 public static boolean isNumeric(String string) {
      return string.matches("^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `anchors` in case of `String.matches`. It's implicit.

Comment: There you go - `+1` for being honest, that you copied. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe regexps could suit your needs:

```java
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    return s.matches("[-+]?[0-9]+");
}

public static boolean isDouble(String s) {
    return s.matches("[-+]?([0-9]+\\.([0-9]+)?|\\.[0-9]+)");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "5.5";
    String s2 = "6";
    System.out.println(isInteger(s1));
    System.out.println(isDouble(s1));
    System.out.println(isInteger(s2));
    System.out.println(isDouble(s2));
}
```

Prints:

```
false
true
true
false
```

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir Are you dealing reputation?! I won't upvote your question, but you're free not to upvote mine ;)

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir.. I assume that you are asking questions on SO, to learn something, and not to buy Reputation. If you are doing so for the later, then rather answer the questions here. And give very good answers, if you know them. Don't urge people here to upvote your posts.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` and `Double.parseDouble` return the integer/double value of the `String`. If the `String` is not a valid number, the method will thrown a `NumberFormatException`.

```
String var1 = "5.5";

try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(var1); // Will fail, var1 has wrong format
    qt += number;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Do your thing if the check fails
}

try {
    double number = Double.parseDouble(var1); // Will succeed
    wt += number;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Do your thing if the check fails
}
```